# Does Android L Developer Preview fix the mm-qcamera-daemon problem?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, nexus-5, camera, developer-preview

I have a Nexus 5 running on Android 4.4.4 Kitkat, and the mm-qcamera-daemon problem appeared today for the first time (I don't have the usual culprits like Snapchat or Skype).

Does Android L Developer Preview fix this issue?

Comment: Since this is a developer preview not intended for full-time, normal use, you may find the cure is worse than the disease: even if this problem is fixed, there might be new problems that are harder to live with.

Comment: @DanHulme Well, yeah maybe, but I can't think of a worse problem than the battery being discharged extremely quickly.

Comment: The battery being discharged extremely quickly such that the CPU melts. That's not likely on a dev preview, though. But deleting all your data, not being able to access the cellular network, or being unable to use a particular app are all more likely outcomes which would be problems for everyday use.

Comment: @DanHulme Thanks, I'm gonna stick to KitKat at least until the official release. Also I thing I found the culprit in my case, because I remember that earlier in the day this app https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nionsoftware.flashlight malfunctioned, and must have caused the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I was still getting this issue (seems to come and go) under android L, so to answer your question, no, it's not fixed.

See https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=70755 for others who are reporting the issue still exists.

Comment: Fast forward to [October 2014](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36996316#comment201) and [December 2014](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36996316#comment217), Google's Android devs claimed that it has been fixed and added a few layers of protection on Android 5.0 Lollipop, though your mileage may vary.